# springamqp retry template and channel error

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Recently we've encountered situation when retry mechanism doesn't handle "low-level" errors. 
Due to our applicative bug, the message we were trying to send was bigger than frame_max size of rabbitmq (default configuration). The problem is that same message causes consumer to be restarted over and over again, and retry mechanism (with 3 max attempts) is not working since it's probably at higher layer (retry template at spring level of consumer) than protocol (withing rabbitmq connection thread).

Is there a way to count low-level failures too and stop at some point to try to handle such message (i.e. max retries)? Am I missing something here? Retry template is simple 3 max retries with some delay in between.
I'm looking for a "robust" way to handle such failures.
thanks in advance

Retry configuration:

```
@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor workMessagesRetryInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().retryOperations(retryTemplate(properties.getRetryMaxAttempts()))
            .recoverer(workerMessageRecoverer())
            .build();
}
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate(int maxRetries) {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(properties.getRetryInitialInterval());
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(properties.getRetryMultiplier());
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(properties.getRetryMaxInterval());
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxRetries);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.registerListener(new LogOnRetryListener());
    return retryTemplate;
}
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setRabbitAdmin(amqpAdmin());
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setQueueNames(properties.getQueueName());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setAdviceChain(workMessagesAdviceChain()); // for retry logic
}
private Advice[] workMessagesAdviceChain() {
    return new Advice[] {workMessagesRetryInterceptor()};
}
```

Full stacktrace

```
2014-11-16 22:29:24,800 [Rabbitmq Connection thread 527] ction.CachingConnectionFactory ERROR> Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=501, reply-text=FRAME_ERROR - type 2, all octets = <<>>: {frame_too_large,183845,131064}, class-id=0, method-id=0)
2014-11-16 22:29:24,852 [xxx.worker.queue3] SimpleMessageListenerContainer WARN > Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports itcom.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=501, reply-text=FRAME_ERROR - type 2, all octets = <<>>: {frame_too_large,183845,131064}, class-id=0, method-id=0)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.checkShutdown(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:245)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:298)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:945)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:934)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1045)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-11-16 22:29:24,853 [xxx.worker.queue3] SimpleMessageListenerContainer INFO > Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-rTulxrbOI4-tOvFr5w9QgQ]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://xxx@ip:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2014-11-16 22:29:24,871 [xxx.worker.queue3] WorkerQueueMessageListenerImpl INFO > Handling WorkMessage[81fd79bedd1d4bea9c2840e33dc31403, SubnetEventAnalysis]
2014-11-16 22:29:25,424 [control.xxx.worker.queue1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer WARN > Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports itcom.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=501, reply-text=FRAME_ERROR - type 2, all octets = <<>>: {frame_too_large,183845,131064}, class-id=0, method-id=0)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:715)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:705)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:660)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:615)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:107)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:540)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-11-16 22:29:25,425 [control.xxx.worker.queue1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer INFO > Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-EOnuPRZyGpbpdnxKumXpMA]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://xxx@ip:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

Comment: could you please share the way you have configured retry mechanism?

Comment: Hi, added. workerMessageRecoverer is custom recoverer that besides calling super.recover adds additional business logic

Comment: Hey @IgorBerman. I know it's been a while since you raised your question but unfortunately I have a very similar problem and just wanted to ask if and how you solved yours? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DanielBubenheim frankly I don't remember, this https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-400 might be connected, not sure though, depends on your version

Comment: Thanks anyway @IgorBerman I got it working by simply increasing the frame_max setting